# SQL Server T-SQL - Arabic format not able to insert directly, but when inserted through c# it works

Tags: t-sql, sql-insert, arabic

```
declare @OfferNameArabic nvarchar(100) = cast(' كوب' as nvarchar(100))
select @OfferNameArabic

set @OfferNameArabic =' كوب'
select @OfferNameArabic
```

When inserted through c#

[image]

When inserted through query

[image]

Comment: `declare @OfferNameArabic nvarchar(100)=N' كوب';
select @OfferNameArabic`

Comment: You have to put the `N` prefix on unicode string literals.

Comment: Have you checked your default database charset, and session charset?  It can can default to non-UTF in a lot of cases unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @MasonStedman Didn't check that

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `N` before string literal:

```
declare @OfferNameArabic nvarchar(100)=N' كوب'; 
select @OfferNameArabic;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d5657a3f7dcf52c1734a02bfc21d2aaf)**